# returning a class object with a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, return, destructor, dynamic-allocation

I have a class

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    char* ptr;
    Foo()  { ptr=new char [10]; }
    ~Foo()  { delete [] ptr;  }
};
```

I have learnt that returning an object of this class is not possible as the dynamically allocated pointer is `delete` 'ed and creates a dangling pointer in the calling function

So how can I return An object of this class??

```
Foo Bar ()
{
    Foo obj;
    return obj;
}
```

Can it be solved by  adding a copy constructor

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo& obj)
{
    ptr = new char [10];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ;++i )
        ptr [i] = obj.ptr[i];
}
```

And the function as

```
Foo Bar ()
{
    Foo obj;
    return Foo(obj);     //invokes copy constructor
}
```

**Note**  These are just representation of the actual class I want and is not created according to recommended standards (ie. Please don't tell me to use `std::string` or `std::vector`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It doesnt explain what to do to overcome it.

Comment: The link shows you that you need a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.

Comment: @WARhead, have you looked the section **Managing Resources** in the first answer?

Comment: @RSahu Yes It still doesnt explain what to do. Unless it is just me not understanding

Comment: @WARhead The link has an example that is practically the same as your code, with a full explanation of the situation and what to do.  Are you not reading the **Managing Resources** section?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and yes I know the rule of three, i was just putting up an example. And I asked if a copy constructor would solve the problem.

Comment: @WARhead -- If you know the rule of three, why are you asking if it will solve the problem?  The rule of 3 is explicitly required to solve your problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes I read it it just points out the unpleasant parts of raw pointers and why to avoid them only.

Comment: @WARhead -- Are you reading the link that I pointed out?  You see exactly how to write a copy constructor and assignment operator.  Are you trolling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130269/discussion-between-warhead-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I return An object of this class??

You need to implement the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator that manage memory properly.

```
// Copy constructor
Foo(Foo const& copy) : ptr(new char[strlen(copy.ptr)+1])
{
  strcpy(ptr, copy.ptr);
}

// Copy assignment operator
Foo& operator=(Foo const& rhs)
{
   // Don't do anything for self assignment
   if ( this != &rhs )
   {
      delete [] ptr;
      ptr = new char[strlen(rhs.ptr)+1]);
      strcpy(ptr, rhs.ptr);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

If `ptr` is always going to be an array of 10 `char`s, you'll need to rethink the copy constructor and copy assignment.

```
// Copy constructor
Foo(Foo const& copy) : ptr(new char[10])
{
  memcpy(ptr, copy.ptr, 10);
}

// Copy assignment operator
Foo& operator=(Foo const& rhs)
{
   // Don't do anything for self assignment
   if ( this != &rhs )
   {
      memcpy(ptr, rhs.ptr, 10);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: int the assignment operator is it `Foo const&` or `const Foo&`?? Or doesn't it make a difference??

Comment: @WARhead, it does not make a difference. I prefer the `Foo const&` coding style.